# Host name unavailable

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

A week ago I changed the nameserver addresses and some other DNS records (A, MX, CNAME) while moving a website from one hosting provider to another.

Everything seemed to work out fine, but apparently the domain name / hostname does not point to anything for some individuals, even after more than 2 days.

**The problem**

From home I am able to reach the website without any problems from both my laptop and mobile devices. However, from work I cannot reach the website while using the same laptop I had used at home. So I thought the network had somehow cached old DNS settings, but this cannot be true, because I can still reach the website from the same network on my mobile devices.

The error at work is just `oops, Google Chrome cannot find [domain]`.

**What I have tried**

I tried to flush the DNS settings at work, but that didn't fix the problem.

Furthermore I tried to ping the domain at work, but it just says

```
ping [domain name]
Ping request could not find host [domain name]. Please check the name and try again.
```

Also I checked http://www.dnsstuff.com/ if the DNS was configured well, but that gave only some warnings, no errors.

Below are the DNS settings listed

[image: DNS settings]

How is it possible that the hostname can not be found, depending on the network used, even though a mobile device can find the hostname on the network for which my laptop cannot? What could possibly be wrong?

---

Edit, `nslookup -debug [domain] 8.8.8.8` gives me:

```
λ nslookup -debug [domain] 8.8.8.8
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa
        name = google-public-dns-a.google.com
        ttl = 21599 (5 hours 59 mins 59 secs)

------------
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        [domain], type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        [domain], type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find [domain]: Server failed
```

Comment: What happens when you `nslookup` the domain? What about `nslookup domain.com 8.8.4.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain has a DNSSEC validation failure, as you can see on http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/gsvnet.nl. There are no RRSIG and DNSKEY records for the domain. This is why Google DNS (and perhaps also other DNS resolvers) return a SERVFAIL for your domain.

From https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq#gdns_validation_failure:

> #### How does Google Public DNS handle lookups which fail DNSSEC validation?
>
> *If Google Public DNS cannot validate a response (due to misconfiguration, missing or incorrect RRSIG records, etc.), it will
> return an error response (SERVFAIL) instead. However, if the impact is
> significant (e.g. a very popular domain is failing validation), we may
> temporarily disable validation on the zone until the problem is
> fixed.*

You should contact your registrar/hosting company and have them disable/fix DNSSEC.

Comment: I tried to flush the cache, but I still can't ping the domain from work.

Comment: Updated my answer, your DNSSEC is broken.

Comment: I requested to disable DNSSEC at the registrars end. Hopefully that will do